# What Type of Brake Pads Should I Look For?

Tags: brakes, parts, brake-pads, replacement

The brake pads on my bike have worn out, so I ordered a new set online, and after I spent a lot of time trying to adjust them, I noticed it won't work as they're not long enough to grip the rim when braking. I'm looking up online, and I can't seem to find anything without those bits and bolts just with a plain long-enough bar.

What name/keyword shall I look up to find what I need?

The Original Brakes:
[image: The Original Brakes]

The New Brake With Bolts That's Short:
[image: The New Brake With Bolts That's Short]

The New Brake Without Bolt Which Is Not Safe Enough:
[image: The New Brake Without Bolt Which Is Not Safe Enough]

**UPDATE:**
Googling "cantilever" was helpful as @mikes mentioned. They seem to be 70mm pads. Also here's another picture from the pads:

[image]

Comment: They look like cantilever brake pads, but you should post a picture of the whole brake as well.

Comment: I think your best bet is to go to a physical bike shop.  Brake pads differ in post style, length, and the hardness of the pad material, and you pretty much need to touch them to see which suits your needs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you search cantilever brake parts you should find what you need. They are sometimes referred to as threadless  post brake pads.

Comment: Also some times they call them canti

Comment: Right, the OP's problem is that he/she bought pads with threaded posts when the old pads are non-threaded.  It should be easy to find the right ones in any shop.

Comment: Thanks. Using those keywords helped me find what I needed. I'm also surprised to see that the question has got no votes but answers get votes! :D

Answer (score 1):

First off, you're best bet is to go to a bike shop and ask for some help.  They'll be happy to help you out and teach you what you need to know.  That being said, if you don't want to or can't make it to a shop, here's my two cents:

Those don't look like cantilever brakes to me - they look like linear pull (or V-Brakes).

mikes' answer is correct in pointing out that you need the ones without threads on the posts.

Something like this will probably work: [http://www.amazon.com/Aztec-Aztec2-Bicycle-Brake-Cantilever/dp/B000FSSMNO](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000FSSMNO)